# Use C variable from Rust without unsafe

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I can expose a C function to Rust code via the FFI as follows:

```
use std::os::raw::c_int;

mod c {
    #[link(name="...")]
    extern "C" {
        pub fn add(a: c_int, b: c_int) -> c_int;
    }
}

pub fn add(a: c_int, b: c_int) -> c_int {
    unsafe {
        c::add(a, b)
    }
}
```

Now I can call `add` from Rust without having to wrap it in another `unsafe` block. But what if I want to do the same for a variable? I.e.:

```
use std::os::raw::c_int;

mod c {
    #[link(name="...")]
    extern "C" {
        pub static VAR: c_int;
    }
}

pub static VAR: c_int = unsafe { c::VAR };
```

This results in a compiler error: "cannot read from extern static". What is the correct way (if there is one) to do this?

Comment: the correct way is to use `unsafe`

Comment: You can still offer some safe interface around that variable through some getter/setter. Within that interface it'll be unsafe, just like the `add` example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be unsafe when it is indeed unsafe, although you can make a static borrow of the imported global variable.

```rust
static VAR: &i32 = unsafe { &c::VAR };
```